# Identifying multipleDC trains on the same track?

Tags: dc, rfid

I'm modifying my DC train system to control the trains from a small chip onboard (arduino or spark core) and I want the trains to be able to know where they are and the controller to know where they are too. There are multiples way to do track detection (a train is on the tracks) but that doesn't tell me what train. I ordered some basic rfid ics to test but I'm bot sure that will work at speed and they are pricey. I thought about maybe using IR but worried that reflections will throw me off. I'd like to have id 12 or so id points around the track so I know what train is where at all times. Any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: How many trains, and at what speed?

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to add a Magnetometer/Compass such as https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-hmc5883l-breakout-triple-axis-magnetometer-compass-sensor/overview

As a train travels its heading changes through each curve allowing you to keep track of its position.  If that doesn't work for you how about activate the magnetometer with a series of small and large magnets.  SSSS = point 1, SSSL = point 2, SSLS = point 3, etc

Comment: Is a magnetometer going to work well near a running motor?

Comment: For this purpose, yes.  The magnetometer would be passing over fixed magnets below the track.

Comment: I thought about the magnets with a hall effect sensor but that limits me to the number of sections. It also doesn't allow the track to know what train is on it either. That would work great for a detection method though.

Comment: Perhaps trains could communicate through ultrasonic train whistle.  A piezo buzzer and a microphone is cheap enough.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a little bit of MCU intelligence into each train. This would hold the train ID which could even be a DIP switch. The MCU would communicate train status with embedded ID back to the central location using wireless communication such as blue tooth or zigby. The MCU would also be responsible for detecting the zone sensors on your track to determine train location.

The sensors could be any number of things including hall cells and magnets. The simplest could even be an infrared photo detector on each train that picks up the narrow directed beam of an infrared LED that is emitting a square wave frequency being driven by a simple 555 circuit. The frequency if each LED would be set preset to like 1kHz, 2kHz .... up to how many ID locations you need.

To eliminate wireless communications you could even setup an RF modulated serial signal that travels down the track riding on the DC voltage.